# All network-related apple processes crash/macOS crash

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, internet

Yesterday, this happened: [image]
I re-installed macOS Sierra. Today, all apple processes related to wifi/network crashed. When I opened system preferences, the app was fine, but as soon as I opened the network pane, it crashed. Whenever  I put my mouse over the wifi menu in the menu bar, my mouse just spun infinitely. Carrot weather, in the sidebar, also crashed, leading me to think that anything related to wifi had crashed.

This is basically what happened in the screenshot, except I tried to relaunch finder, and when finder wouldn't launch tried launching it from the menu bar.

I'm pretty sure that the (relatively new wd) ssd is fine (SSDReporter said it was, and diskutility didn't find any errors), so what can the problem be?

Restarting seems to temporarily fix the problem.

MacBook Pro, mid-2012, 16gb ram, data doubler instead of superdrive.

SIP disabled.

Do I need to replace the wifi card?

`

```
ls /Library/LaunchAgents

at.obdev.LittleSnitchUIAgent.plist
com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist
com.adobe.ARMDCHelper.cc24aef4a1b90ed56a725c38014c95072f92651fb65e1bf9c8e43c37a23d420d.plist
com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist
com.adobe.GC.AGM.plist
com.adobe.GC.Invoker-1.0.plist
com.divx.dms.agent.plist
com.divx.uninstall.converter.plist
com.divx.uninstall.player.plist
com.divx.uninstall.preferences.plist
com.divx.update.agent.plist
com.malwarebytes.mbam.frontend.agent.plist
com.microsoft.update.agent.plist
com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
com.paragon-software.ntfs.notification-agent.plist
com.parallels.mobile.prl_deskctl_agent.launchagent.plist
com.teamviewer.teamviewer.plist
com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop.plist
org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist
`

`
ls /Library/LaunchDaemons

PT.updd.plist
at.obdev.littlesnitchd.plist
com.BlueStacks.AppPlayer.bstservice_helper.plist
com.MagnetismStudios.endurance.helper.plist
com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator.plist
com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper.plist
com.adobe.acc.installer.plist
com.adobe.acc.installer.v2.plist
com.adobe.agsservice.plist
com.adobe.fpsaud.plist
com.ambrosiasw.ambrosiaaudiosupporthelper.daemon.plist
com.apple.installer.cleanupinstaller.plist
com.au.GetflixHelper.plist
com.bjango.istatmenus.fans.plist
com.bjango.istatmenus.installerhelper.plist
com.bombich.ccchelper.plist
com.cleverfiles.cfbackd.plist
com.datarobotics.ddservice64d.plist
com.datarobotics.ddserviced.plist
com.mackeeper.MacKeeper.MacKeeperPrivilegedHelper.plist
com.malwarebytes.mbam.rtprotection.daemon.plist
com.malwarebytes.mbam.settings.daemon.plist
com.mice.360Daemon.plist
com.microsoft.OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.plist
com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist
com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper.plist
com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
com.paragon-software.installer.plist
com.paragon-software.ntfs.loader.plist
com.paragon-software.ntfsd.plist
com.paragon-software.snapshot.plist
com.paragon-software.vdmounter.plist
com.parallels.desktop.launchdaemon.plist
com.parallels.mobile.dispatcher.launchdaemon.plist
com.parallels.mobile.kextloader.launchdaemon.plist
com.rogueamoeba.aceagent.plist
com.sidefx.hqserver.plist
com.sonos.SonosLibraryServer.plist
com.stclairsoft.AppTamerAgent.plist
com.sweetpproductions.WiFiSpoofHelperTool.plist
com.teamviewer.Helper.plist
com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist
com.tunabellysoftware.TGFanHelper.plist
com.twocanoes.WincloneHelper.plist
net.freemacsoft.LiteIcon.LIHelperTool.plist
net.tunnelblick.tunnelblick.tunnelblickd.plist
org.cindori.TEHelper.plist
org.cindori.noatime.plist
org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist
org.pqrs.Karabiner.load.plist
org.pqrs.NoEjectDelay.load.plist
org.virtualbox.startup.plist
org.wireshark.ChmodBPF.plist
```

`

TL;DR: macOS seems to be crashing, may be related to wifi.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90294/discussion-on-question-by-sam-all-network-related-apple-processes-crash-macos-cr).

Comment: @Allan, according to apple Internet recovery installs the latest compatible macOS, so would an installer thumb drive work instead?

Comment: @Allan, will I have to reinstall drivers and homebrew/stuff installed by homebrew? Should I use restore from backup (after wiping and installing Sierra), or move all the files like applications, downloads, application support, etc. over manually? Also, I haven't had a chance to install it yet, I was at school so I'm going to start as soon as I know what I should do

Comment: Rebooting booting into one of my clones to erase and install from there

Comment: It turns out that I can't do that, or boot into any of their recovery partitions, trying something else now