# How can I kill/launch wifi from terminal

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, force-quit

Linked to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/352556/305111)

Is there any way to literally kill wifi (wifi process/wifi related processes?) and then launch/relaunch it, all with terminal?

maybe `sudo killall WiFiAgent`?

macOS Sierra (10.12)

Comment: What makes you believe that the WiFi process is somehow at fault?

Answer (score 2):

As found [here](https://www.mattcrampton.com/blog/managing_wifi_connections_using_the_mac_osx_terminal_command_line/):

Wifi can be turned on and off using

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```

and back on using

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

When I use this, it says something along the lines of `en0` is not wifi, turning on/off `en1` instead, presumably because en0 is my ethernet connection.

**EDIT:** Also, this should be a comment, but I cannot yet comment, but `sudo killall WiFiAgent` does not appear to do anything on my computer.

Comment: This *turns off* Wi-Fi.  It doesn't kill the process.

Comment: @Allan I assumed it would kill the process, but if it doesn't, then I'm not sure how to do that